# Plastic ring on new Shimano crankset, toss or keep?

Tags: crankset

I just got a new Shimano crankset and it has this plastic ring on the "inside" of the small chainring.  I'm thinking that this just some packing material.  Am I right and can I toss it, or is this a real part?

[image]

Comment: Did you check the technical diagram for the crankset you got?

Comment: @batman, checked the paper first.  It only gives specs for common models, and specs for compatible bottom brackets, and very light instruction (seriously, one step stuff) for installing a bottom bracket and what Allen key for the crank bolts.  Doc number is si-0094a-001

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://cycle.shimano.co.kr/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Alivio-Acera/SI_0094A/SI-0094A-001-ENG_v1_m56577569830667768.PDF&ved=0ahUKEwjwsb_rq7_MAhUClxoKHRpqD70QFggeMAA&usg=AFQjCNHn6vZUT-RiIyb3HvGWH2QEDeterQ&sig2=7aERi8KYQERC64Yzp4zPiA

Comment: You're looking for something like EV-FC-M411-2466C http://bike.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/FC/EV-FC-M411-2466C_v1_m56577569830724278.pdf.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I haven't seen one of those before, but it looks as though it could stop the chain dropping between the bottom bracket shell (the bike frame) and the crankset if you ever drop the chain off the inside of the small ring. When that happens it can be tricky to get it back out, and if the chain is oily you end up with that oil everywhere (mostly on your hands and clothes). This is something I see occasionally, as I stop to help people standing next to their bike looking helpless on my ride to work. On some bikes it's possible to get the chain wiggled in such that it's still movable but you can't get it out without taking the crank off (I've seen that in the bike shop).

I would leave the plastic ring in place just in case is stops that happening. It's one of those "5 grams stops the once in 10 years problem" things.

It might also reduce damage from the chain rubbing on the frame if the chains falls off as above.

Edit: after Batman found the part (Shimano EV-FC-M410-2465A), here's a diagram of something very similar via [this pdf link](http://bike.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/FC/EV-FC-M410-2465A_v1_m56577569830608877.pdf)

[image: excerpt of Shimano pdf diagram]

Comment: I considered that as well.  I'm willing to bet you are right since if has branding and stuff on it.  There wasn't any other packing material besides a small cover to keep the teeth from digging into the box.  I figured it could be there to keep the ring bolts from digging in the box.

Comment: According to Shimano EV-FC-M410-2465A, this is the correct answer -- it is a chain protector.

Comment: @Batman wow, actual official documentation. Well found!

Answer (score 0):

On my set up, the ring was hitting spacer washers behind the cartridge on the bottom bracket.   It was OK after the spacer was removed.